# Share a number from call history to calendar

Tags: calls, calendar, call-history

On my s3, I would like to make a calendar entry after some one called me and put the number in the description field on the calendar.

I'm thinking this would be easy, just share the number from call history to calendar. Unfortunately "share" is not available and I can only "send number" as an sms.

Is there an app that can help me with this?

Is there a reason the s3 doesn't have this obvious feature?

Comment: +1 interesting, however I wouldn't say it was an 'obvious feature'. This seems similar to what you want: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileapptek.talknotes.beta&hl=en

Comment: It just seems very un-android-ish to hard code send with sms, and not just a share.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit roundabout, but it works:-

1. From the call log, click **Create contact**.
2. On the screen for creating a contact, long-tap the phone number field to select it and bring up the special *action mode* buttons for selected text.
3. Click the 'copy' icon. (That's the one to the right of the pair of scissors.)
4. Click **Cancel** to cancel creating the contact, and answer **OK** to the confirmation dialog.
5. Switch to the calendar app and create a new event, or edit the event you want to change.
6. Long-tap some empty space in the description and click **Paste**.

As for why the S3's **Phone** app doesn't let you copy the number to the clipboard directly, or share it, only Samsung can tell us that.

Comment: How is the vanilla android call history? Can I copy or share the number from there?

Comment: @Esben: On my Galaxy Nexus, when viewing the call in the call log, there is an option in the overflow menu: "Edit number before call". That pulls up the phone app with the phone number in the number field, and I can copy the text as in any other field. But no, there's no "share" option. (Nor is there a share option in the Google Voice app for "Missed calls".)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Samsung Galaxy Note Edge either.  However I found a way out to copy the phone number in the log this way:

1. Select the phone number and click Send number under the option;
2. The selected phone number will appear under New message; and
3. Long press the phone number and do the necessary to cut or copy to the desired    location.