# "Share" a phone call

Tags: call-history, share-menu

I would like to "share" meta data from a phone call with any app, using Android's standard sharing feature. The idea is to create a note in e.g. Podio or Evernote after receiving or placing an important phone call.

Ideally, the shared text should include both the phone number and start time of the call.

I saw [this roundabout "solution"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47108/share-a-number-from-call-history-to-calendar), which is to simply copy the phone number and paste it, but I would like a quicker solution.

Is there any phone call log app that lets me do this? I have tried the (Sony) stock app, Call Log+ and Call Log Monitor.